# Plotly: How to highlight the line (change width of the line) on mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, charts, plotly

I would like to highlight the line (change width of the line) on mouse hover event, like guys from highcharts do. Please check https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare

Is it possible to do that?

Link to the question on plotly web site -
 https://community.plot.ly/t/how-to-highlight-the-line-change-width-of-line-on-mouse-over/5128